# Replacement capacitors for Celestion DL6 crossover

Tags: audio, speakers

I have a couple of Celestion DL6 speakers that are more than 30 years old. Not quite as good as they used to be, it seems. I assume the electroytics deteriorate? In which case I need to replace them.
The values are 4uF and 6uF, rated for 50V.

So:

Should I replace with non-polarized aluminium electrolytics?

Should I choose another type eg film?

Any other comments or reccommendations?

[image]

Comment: It seems that you are asking for opinions. My opinion is, you should first test the capacitors if they even need replacing.

Comment: @Justme And how would I do that? A simple DC test would not be sufficient, I assume

Comment: @Justme I am not merely asking for opinions. I want to know what current best practice is

Comment: Isn't "current best practice" an obvious matter of opinion? I don't think there is any standards body that would govern this.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson No standards body, but certainly greatly differeing prices when it comes to what capacitors are used in expensive versus cheap speaker. At least, I assume so. For example, electrolytics degrate faster than (say) polypropylene but for the same capacitance the latter are far more expensive

Comment: Why do you think the capacitors are the problem? Have you tested them? Do they show excessive ESR?